# How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in a string in Perl?

Tags: perl, capitalize, title-case

What is the easiest way to capitalize the first letter in each word of a string?

Comment: In know this is late, but the first letter of each word capitalized is *not* title case. Unfortunately this is the first page that comes up in a google search for "perl title case".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [the faq](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-capitalize-all-the-words-on-one-line).

I don't believe `ucfirst()` satisfies the OP's question to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string without splitting the string and joining it later.

Comment: Err, \U is internally implemented by calling ucfirst, so your statement about it contradicts your own advice. :-)

Comment: The s///g switch iterates, so it does the whole string. When I first saw another answer with just "look at the ucfirst function" I felt at least more about split/join should be mentioned, and I see the person posting edited to include those already.

Comment: You don't want to use the advice you gave, which is the code the FAQ uses to show the wrong way to do it. Read the text right after that bit where I explain why that answer is wrong. :)

Comment: I've now modified the FAQ to remove the wrong answer everyone is latching onto because they didn't read the second paragraph.

Answer (score 57):

As @brian is mentioning in the comments the currently accepted answer by @piCookie is wrong!

```
$_="what's the wrong answer?";
s/\b(\w)/\U$1/g
print;
```

This will print "What'S The Wrong Answer?" notice the wrongly capitalized S

As the [FAQ](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How_do_I_capitalize_) says you are probably better off using

```
s/([\w']+)/\u\L$1/g
```

or  [Text::Autoformat](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::Autoformat)

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at the [ucfirst](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) function.

```
$line = join " ", map {ucfirst} split " ", $line;
```

Comment: Note that split(" ", $line) splits on arbitrary whitespaces, so that won't preserve all whitespaces.

Comment: Agreed; the correct answer would be `$line = join " ", map {ucfirst} split / /, $line;` (note the " changed to /)

Comment: @Ether: Closer, but it still strips _trailing_ spaces (and wouldn't recognize words separated by `\t` only).

Comment: A bigger problem is that `ucfirst` doesn't actually lowercase the string. Title case isn't `FOO` and this won't fix that.

Answer (score 11):

```
$capitalized = join '', map { ucfirst lc $_ } split /(\s+)/, $line;
```

By capturing the whitespace, it is inserted in the list and used to rebuild the original spacing. "ucfirst lc" capitalizes "teXT" to "Text".

Comment: Does not handle `"bill o’hanlon"`.

Comment: You probably want to use `split /(\W+)/` then.

Answer (score 7):

```
$string =~ s/(\w+)/\u$1/g;
```

should work just fine

Comment: Wouldn't this uppercase the entire string, instead of the 1st letter of each word?

Comment: @briandfoy: your link is broken.  Point to this: http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-capitalize-all-the-words-on-one-line-

Comment: If you add a space, this might work: `s/ (\w+)/\u$1/g;`.

Answer (score 2):

This capitalizes only the first word of each line:

```
perl -ne "print (ucfirst($1)$2)  if s/^(\w)(.*)/\1\2/" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the FAQ solution doesn't work if you have words that are in all-caps and you want them to be (only) capitalized instead. You can either make a more complicated regex, or just do a lc on the string before applying the FAQ solution.

Comment: The FAQ solution works just fine because there are actually several solution in the FAQ. The best solution is Damian's Text::Autoformat, which solves exactly your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use '[Title Case](http://daringfireball.net/2008/05/title_case)', its a very cool piece of code written in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
echo "what's the wrong answer?" |perl -pe 's/^/ /; s/\s(\w+)/ \u$1/g; s/^ //'
```

Output will be:

```
What's The Wrong Answer?
```

Answer (score -1):

The [ucfirst](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) function in a map certainly does this, but only in a very rudimentary way. If you want something a bit more sophisticated, have a look at [John Gruber's TitleCase script](http://daringfireball.net/2008/08/title_case_update).