# Capitalize / Capitalise first letter of every word in a string in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, capitalize

What's the best way to capitalize / capitalise the first letter of every word in a string in Matlab?

i.e.
*the rain in spain falls mainly on the plane*
to
*The Rain In Spain Falls Mainly On The Plane*

Comment: Would it be possible to accept one of the answers, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So using the string

```
str='the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.'
```

Simply use regexp replacement function in Matlab, regexprep

```
regexprep(str,'(\<[a-z])','${upper($1)}')

ans =

The Rain In Spain Falls Mainly On The Plain.
```

The `\<[a-z]` matches the first character of each word to which you can convert to upper case using `${upper($1)}`

This will also work using `\<\w` to match the character at the start of each word.

```
regexprep(str,'(\<\w)','${upper($1)}')
```

Comment: Cheers - although I can't claim too much credit as it's just a slightly tweaked example from the help pages on regular expressions. The string replacement section gives an example for capitalizing the first letter of each sentance in a string.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Matlab comes with [build in Perl](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/perl.html), for every complicated string or file processing tasks Perl scripts can be used. So you could maybe use something like this:

```
[result, status] = perl('capitalize.pl','the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plane')
```

where capitalize.pl is a Perl script as follows:

```
$input  = $ARGV[0];
$input =~ s/([\w']+)/\u\L$1/g;
print $input;
```

The perl code was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226/perl-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string) Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Loads of ways:

```
str = 'the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plane'

spaceInd = strfind(str, ' '); % assume a word is preceded by a space
startWordInd = spaceInd+1;  % words start 1 char after a space
startWordInd = [1, startWordInd]; % manually add the first word
capsStr = upper(str);

newStr = str;
newStr(startWordInd) = capsStr(startWordInd)
```

More elegant/complex -- cell-arrays, textscan and cellfun are very useful for this kind of thing:

```
str = 'the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plane'

function newStr = capitals(str)

    words = textscan(str,'%s','delimiter',' '); % assume a word is preceded by a space
    words = words{1};

    newWords = cellfun(@my_fun_that_capitalizes, words, 'UniformOutput', false);
    newStr = [newWords{:}];

        function wOut = my_fun_that_capitalizes(wIn)
            wOut = [wIn ' ']; % add the space back that we used to split upon
            if numel(wIn)>1
                wOut(1) = upper(wIn(1));
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    str='the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.' ;
for i=1:length(str)
    if str(i)>='a' && str(i)<='z'
        if i==1 || str(i-1)==' '
            str(i)=char(str(i)-32); % 32 is the ascii distance between uppercase letters and its lowercase equivalents
        end
    end
end
```

Less ellegant and efficient, more readable and maintainable.