# How to make only the first character in each word uppercase in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string containing all uppercase words and I want to make only the first letter of each word uppercase or convert all but the first character to lowercase. I've been messing around with regex for a while and can't get it right.

Comment: Does it need to use regex? If not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-perl\

Comment: @OnlineCop The second answer to that question shows how to do this with a regex. This is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $str = "FOOBAR FOOBAR";
$str =~ s/(\S+)/\u\L$1/g;
print $str;
```

output

```
Foobar Foobar
```

Check [`ucfirst`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html) and [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) in perldoc.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect job for [ucfirst()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ucfirst.html), no need regex here :

```
$ echo 'FOO   BAR BASE' |
    perl -nE '$_ = lc($_); say join " ", map { ucfirst $_ } split /\s/'
```

Output:

```
Foo   Bar Base
```